# Python EOFError in while loop when using raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, raw-input, eoferror

I can't figure out how to avoid the EOFError on the second iteration of the while loop right after prompting for raw_input. I need this loop to run 30 times and ideally wouldnt have a try-except block that would boot me from the program. Any help would be appreciated!`

```
import sys
import pyaudio
import wave
import os
import fcntl
import time

def main():
    sound_cues = open('sound_cues').read().splitlines()
    light_cues = open('light_cues').read().splitlines()
    play_names = open('play_names').read().splitlines()
    plays = []

    for idx in range(len(play_names)):
        plays.append( {'name': play_names[idx], 'sound': sound_cues[idx], 'lights': light_cues[idx]} )

    while(True):
        play_num = raw_input("Enter a play number: ")

        play = plays[int(play_num) - 1]
        print
        print 'lights:'
        print play['lights']
        print
        raw_input("Press Enter to start sound...")
        print
        print 'sound:'
        print play['sound']

        audio = "sounds/" + play['sound']

        wf = wave.open(audio)
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

        data = wf.readframes(1024)
        fl = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        print
        print "Press Enter to stop audio..."
        print
        while data != '':
            try:
                stdin = sys.stdin.read()
                if "\n" in stdin or "\r" in stdin:
                    break
            except IOError:
                pass
            stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(1024)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`

the output is `

```
Enter a play number: 2

lights:
Black out, clamp light works as spot, follows Kris

Press Enter to start sound...

sound:
1.wav

Press Enter to stop audio...


Enter a play number: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "30plays_1.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "30plays_1.py", line 18, in main
    play_num = raw_input("Enter a play number: ")
EOFError
```

`

Comment: You are mixing the use of `sys.stdin.read()` and `raw_input`. I'm guessing after the `read()`, `stdin` becomes empty and `raw_input` throws an EOFError.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried construcing a minimal working example that reproduces the error? I am running python on windows, so I can't try everything you are doing, as `fcntl` is unix specific, but I would suggest that you start removing parts of your code (like reading and playing the file) until the error disappears.

Also, you are opening files and streams but never explicitely close them, e.g. you are calling `stream = p.open(...)`, but there's no `stream.stop_stream()` and
`stream.close()`, as well as no `wf.close()`. This is probably not related to your error, but it is good practice to close files and not to rely on garbage collection.